# Multiple arrays in a class and XCode

Tags: c++

I am trying to use XCode for my project and have this code in my .h:

```
class FileReader
{
private:
    int numberOfNodes;
    int startingNode;
    int numberOfTerminalNodes;
    int terminalNode[];
    int numberOfTransitions;
    int transitions[];

public:
    FileReader();
    ~FileReader();

};
```

I get a "Field has incomplete type int[]" error on the terminalNode line... but not on the transitions line. What could be going on? I'm SURE that's the correct syntax?

Comment: But this is not related to Xcode. Retagged.

Comment: Thanks, I tried compiling manually and it didn't throw an error so i thought it might be Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the size of an array is part of its type, and an array must have a (greater than zero) size.

There's an extension that allows an array of indeterminate size as the last element of a class. This is used to conveniently access a variable sized array as the last element of a struct.

```
struct S {
    int size;
    int data[];
};

S *make_s(int size) {
    S *s = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S) + sizeof(int)*size);
    s->size = size;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    S *s = make_s(4);
    for (int i=0;i<s->size;++i)
        s->data[i] = i;
    free(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is unfortunately not valid C++, but it *is* valid C (C99 or C11). If you've inherited this from some C project, you may be surprised that this works there but not in C++. But the truth of the matter is that you can't have zero-length arrays (which is what the incomplete array `int transitions[]` is in this context) in C++.

Use a `std::vector<int>` instead. Or a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

(Or, if you're really really really fussy about not having two separate memory allocations, you can write your own wrapper class which allocates one single piece of memory and in-place constructs both the preamble and the array. But that's excessive.)

---

The original C use would have been something like:

```
FileReader * p = malloc(sizeof(FileReader) + N * sizeof(int));
```

Then you could have used `p->transitions[i]`, for `i` in `[0, N)`.

Such a construction obviously doesn't make sense in the object model of C++ (think constructors and exceptions).

Comment: Wow, that is very weird. I was simply thinking about this in C, trying to make the project as simple as possible. My intent was to actually allocate the array in the constructor. I swear I remember doing that in a programming class. Oh well, vectors will work fine.

Comment: @Kyle: Just between us, I did actually write a fully C++ version of this idea, but it's fairly gargantuan, and almost entirely useless.

Comment: @Kyle arrays and pointers are not the same thing. If you want to manually allocate an array then you should use a pointer type instead of an array type. (although a vector is a better idea, as you say)

Comment: @bames53: Zero-length arrays are a very C-style optimization: If the entire thing is already dynamically allocated, then you get the array "for free", and also shoved inside the padding area of the struct. It's not quite the same as a pointer plus additional allocation.

Comment: @Kerrek
This is for a class, so it doesn't really matter if it is useful, lol.

The pointer allocation must be the way I was thinking of, maybe my compilers just weren't as picky before.

Comment: He said he planned to allocate the array in the constructor. That only makes sense if that 'zero-length' array in the middle is intended to be a pointer to the allocation he performs in the constructor.

Comment: @bames53: You can separate allocation and construction and still make this work: Allocate the whole memory, then inplace-construct the preamble and the array...

Comment: That doesn't make sense for an array in the middle of a class, only arrays at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an unbound array length in a header -- there is no way for the compiler to know the class size, thus it can never be instantiated.

Its likely that the lack of error on the transitions line is a result of handling the first error.  That is, if you comment out terminalNode, transitions should give the error.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. If you're inside a struct definition, the compiler **needs** to know the size of the struct, so it also needs to know the size of all its elements. Because `int []` means an array of ints of any length, its size is unknown. Either use a fixed-size array (`int field[128];`) or a pointer that you'll use to malloc memory (`int *field;`).